# memory increase when loop mount and remount in React 18

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a UI SDK, when SDK invoke will render React Component, and close will unmount to close UI.

My SDK was working in webview all day, and almost never reboot.

User feedback UI can not interactive when SDK working long time. So I Guess SDK has memory leak.

Below was small reproduce, and inspect memory in chrome devtools, memory was increased  when loop mount and remount.

how can i fix it?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <button>render</button>
      <button>unmount</button>
    </>
  );
};

const dom = document.getElementById("root");

const render = () => {
  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(dom);

  root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  );

  setTimeout(() => root.unmount(), 100);
};

window.__begain = () => setInterval(render, 2000);
```

[image]